# How Can I merge complex shapes stored in an ArrayList with Geomerative Library

Tags: arraylist, merge, processing, shapes

I store shapes of this class:

```
class Berg{
  int vecPoint;
  float[] shapeX;
  float[] shapeY;

  Berg(float[] shapeX, float[] shapeY, int vecPoint){
    this.shapeX = shapeX;
    this.shapeY = shapeY;
    this.vecPoint = vecPoint;
  }

  void display(){
    beginShape();
      curveVertex(shapeX[vecPoint-1], shapeY[vecPoint-1]);
      for(int i=0;i<vecPoint;i++){
        curveVertex(shapeX[i], shapeY[i]);
      }
      curveVertex(shapeX[0],shapeY[0]);
      curveVertex(shapeX[1],shapeY[1]);
    endShape();
  }
}
```

in an ArrayList with

```
shapeList.add(new Berg(xBig,yBig,points));
```

The shapes are defined with eight (curveVertex-)points (xBig and yBig) forming a shape around a randomly positioned center.
After checking if the shapes are intersecting I want to merge the shapes that overlap each other. I already have the detection of the intersection working but struggle to manage the merging.

I read that the library Geomerative has a way to do something like that with [union()](http://www.forkable.eu/utils/processing/documentation/geomerative/rg_method_union.htm) but RShapes are needed as parameters.
So my question is: How can I change my shapes into the required RShape type? Or more general (maybe I did some overall mistakes): How Can I merge complex shapes stored in an ArrayList with or without Geomerative Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the API for RShape: http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/documentation/geomerative/RShape.html

That lists the constructors and methods you can use to create an `RShape` out of a series of points. It might look something like this:

```
class Berg{
  public RShape toRShape(){
    RShape rShape = new rShape();
    for(int i = 0; i < shapeX; i++){
      rShape.addLineto(shapeX[i], shapeY[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
I added this
`public RShape toRShape(){
    RShape rShape = new rShape();
    for(int i = 0; i < shapeX.length; i++){
      rShape.addLineTo(shapeX[i], shapeY[i]);
    }
  }` 
to my class but it has some problems with `new rShape();` saying that this is a not existing class. I seem to miss something obvious.

Comment: @Wintergoldhähnchen Did you include the library in your sketch? Did you import the `RShape` class?

Comment: It took a while, but
`public void toRShape(){
    RShape rShape = new RShape();
    for(int i = 0; i < shapeX.length; i++){
      rShape.addLineTo(shapeX[i], shapeY[i]);
    }
  }`
finally did it for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Wintergoldhähnchen No problem. Note that your code doesn't actually do anything with the `RShape` created. But if that works, you might consider marking the answer as correct :p